# Delete rows and localStorage keys upon sorting in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, sorting

I have a simple table that is loading data from `localStorage`. Upon clicking on Delete button the rows are deleted (1 per click) and key from `localStorage` is deleted.

**TL;DR `orderBy` is causing to lose the track of index**

Now, the issue happened when I have introduced "sort" and "reverse sort" feature.
To cut the story short, here is my code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'firstName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'firstName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">First Name</span>
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-up"></span>
                        <span ng-show="sortedType == 'lastName' && !sortedReverse" class="fa fa-long-arrow-down"></span>
                        <span href="#" ng-click="sortedType = 'lastName'; sortedReverse = !sortedReverse" style="cursor:pointer;">Last Name</span>
                    </th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="(k, v) in retrievedData | orderBy: sortedType: sortedReverse">
                <td>{{v.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{v.lastName}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow();">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

ctrl.js:

```
    app.controller('ctrl', function ($window, $scope) {

        $scope.initData = [
            {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe",  
            },
            {
                firstName: "Jane",
                lastName: "Doe",
            },
            {
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Smith",
            }
        ];



if(!localStorage.getItem('initData')) {
    $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
}
        $scope.retrievedData = JSON.parse($window.localStorage.getItem('initData'));
        $scope.sortedType = 'firstName';
        $scope.sortedReverse = false;
        //Remove Rows and Update localStorage Key Values
        $scope.removeRow = function(row) {
            $scope.retrievedData.splice(row, 1);
            $scope.initData.splice(row, 1);
            $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
        }
    });
```

What happens here is, when I sort the data (and it is automatically sorted by `firstName`) or when I do the reverse sorting, and click delete, the first row that is deleted is always the first `object` in my `array`. So, lets say I want to delete row where `"John Smith"` is and I click "delete" button, the "`John Doe"` object gets deleted. I have tried to solve this by `.indexOf()`, but I couldn't.

Here is what I've tried:

```
$scope.removeRow = function(rowIndex) {
        var index = $scope.retrievedData.indexOf(rowIndex);
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(index, 1);
        $scope.initData.splice(index, 1);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.initData));
        console.log($scope.retrievedData.indexOf(rowIndex));
    }
```

So, I've tried to keep a track of index with `.indexOf()`, but my `console.log()` outputs `-1` and now the last object is deleted.

What can I do here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Array.prototype to get the index value in an array of objects.

In your HTML,Pass the name to the function call.

```
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Edit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="removeRow(v.firstName);">Delete</button>
        </td>
```

And change your removeRow function like this.You have to set 'initData' in your localstorage to `$scope.retrievedData` because everytime you refresh your page, initData is getting reinitialised and so  splicing initData and again setting it to localstorage is not logical.

```
$scope.removeRow = function(name) {
        var index = $scope.retrievedData.indexOfname(name);
        $scope.retrievedData.splice(index, 1);
        //$scope.initData.splice(index, 1);
        $window.localStorage.setItem('initData', JSON.stringify($scope.retrievedData));
        console.log($scope.retrievedData.indexOf(rowIndex));
    }

Array.prototype.indexOfname = function(name) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++)
        if (this[i].name === name)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

You can also find the index of an object in an array of objects by using findIndex

```
var index = $scope.retrievedData.findIndex(obj => obj.firstName=== name);
```

Comment: Give me a minute please, but why my method didn't work, using plainly indexOf()?

Comment: I think indexOf() works on an array of strings or numbers. What is rowIndex? You are not passing any parameter in your HTML to removeRow() function.

Comment: Oh, you are right.. what could be passed in this function as an argument?

Comment: You can pass the firstname like I did above. Is it working now?

Comment: This is working fine, but there is now another issue.. Are you still here, so I can explain?

Comment: Yeah, What is the other issue?

Comment: Well.. the first time I do this and refresh the data is saved in the localStorage as it should be. But after the refresh if I delete some other row and refresh, the data is getting added up.. Only after the first refresh everything looks fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146889/discussion-between-vivz-and-tholo).

Comment: Thanks so much mate. :)